# iOS, Adding new Core Data object in each row in a Table View

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to add within a Table View a new Core Data object and trying to name each row with a new number. Something similar to the Master Detail template in Xcode but with numbers and not dates. It should begin with 1 and then follow with 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. But it currently adds the object but only shows the number 1. Maybe this is a simple error I am making with the logic, could someone point it out and help? Here is the code:

```
-(void)addNewRow {
 // Create and configure a new instance of the Event entity.
    Hoyo *hoyo = (Hoyo *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Hoyo" inManagedObjectContext:context];

//Here I am trying to get the current value in the object which is 0
NSNumber *coreNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[hoyo numero]integerValue]];// 0

NSNumber *myNum = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:0];//0
int currentNumber = [coreNumber integerValue] + 1;//0 +1 = 1
NSNumber *newNum = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:currentNumber];

NSLog(@"El numero de hoyo es: %@", [hoyo numero]);


if (([[hoyo numero] isEqualToNumber:coreNumber]) || ([[hoyo numero] isEqualToNumber:myNum])) {

    [hoyo setNumero:newNum];
    [array insertObject:hoyo atIndex:0];
} 


NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    // Handle the error.
}



NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: In your code, you're only inserting 1 object. Is that intended?

Comment: I'm curious about this code, naSH, and don't recognize this (presumably Spanish language) syntax in your code. Specifically `[hoyo numero]` and `[hoyo setNumero]` look like you may've defined them yourself in your Core Data class, and if so, is certainly another couple of points for potential failure. Can you explain more about your code if the problem is still at issue, please?